# Django how to handle custom user class' password field?

Tags: python, django, https, passwords

I have a server running Django 1.6.6 and an application build by phonegap/cordova to Android and iOS.

First question:
Because I have some custom requirements to the "User" class I do not want to use the User-class offered by Django.

So I have the following class:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField()
    createdat = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.username)
```

So if I or an other admin logs into the "Admin"-backend offered by Django he can see the passwords of the users as plain text.
Is there a way to create something like

```
password = models.PasswordField(max_length=16)
```

to avoid reading the passwords in the backend?

The second question is, if sending the password via ajax like this

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url : 'https://myproject.mydomain.com/login/',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            'username' : username,
            'password' : password
        },
        timeout : 30000,
        success : function(data) {
            //do success stuff
        },
        error : function(x, t, m) {
            //do error stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

with "https" is secure for passwords? Or is there an other way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Since Django 1.5+ you can extend(Inheritance) the User model with your own requirements + what already has been provided to you in that class. Are you sure you want to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Yes, because if it is possible to get the required security to the password field it is much easier for me.
So I have to leave the password blank until the user registers. And I want to use self generated pks and not "1", "2", "3", ...